# FastAPI read configuration before specifying dependencies

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm using [fastapi-azure-auth](https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/) to make call to my API impossible, if the user is not logged in (doesn't pass a valid token in the API call from the UI to be precise).

**My question doesn't have anything to do with this particular library, it's about FastAPI in general.**

I use a class (`SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer`) which is callable. It is used in two cases:

- `api.onevent("startup")` - to connect to Azure
- as a dependency in routes that user wants to have authentication in

To initialize it, it requires some things like Azure IDs etc. I provide those via a config file.

The problem is, this class is created when the modules get evaluated, so the values from the config file would have to be already present.

So, I have this:

dependecies.py

```py
azure_scheme = SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer(
    app_client_id=settings.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    tenant_id=settings.TENANT_ID,
    scopes={
        f'api://{settings.APP_CLIENT_ID}/user_impersonation': 'user_impersonation',
    }
)
```

api.py

```py
from .dependencies import azure_scheme

api = FastAPI(
   title="foo"
)

def init_api() -> FastAPI:
   # I want to read configuration here
   api.swagger_ui.init_oauth = {"clientID": config.CLIENT_ID}
   return api

@api.on_event('startup')
async def load_config() -> None:
    """
    Load OpenID config on startup.
    """
    await azure_scheme.openid_config.load_config()

@api.get("/", dependencies=[Depends(azure_scheme)])
def test():
   return {"hello": "world"}
```

Then I'd run the app with `gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker foo:init_api()`.

So, for example, the `Depends` part will get evaluated before `init_api`, before reading the config. I would have to read the config file before that happens. And I don't want to do that, I'd like to control when the config reading happens (that's why I have `init_api` function where I initialize the logging and other stuff).

My question would be: is there a way to first read the config then initialize a dependency like `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer` so I can use the values from config for this initialization?

@Edit

api.py:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from .config import get_config
from .dependencies import get_azure_scheme

api = FastAPI(
    title="Foo",
    swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url="/oauth2-redirect",
)
api.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


def init_api() -> FastAPI:
    api.swagger_ui_init_oauth = {
        "usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant": True,
        "clientId": get_config().client_id,
    }
    return api


@api.get("/test", dependencies=[Depends(get_azure_scheme)])
def test():
    return Response(status_code=200)
```

config.py:

```py
import os
from functools import lru_cache

import toml
from pydantic import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    client_id: str
    tenant_id: str


@lru_cache
def get_config():
    with open(os.getenv("CONFIG_PATH", ""), mode="r") as config_file:
        config_data = toml.load(config_file)

    return Settings(
        client_id=config_data["azure"]["CLIENT_ID"], tenant_id=config_data["azure"]["TENANT_ID"]
    )
```

dependencies.py:

```py
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi_azure_auth import SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer

from .config import Settings, get_config


def get_azure_scheme(config: Settings = Depends(get_config)):
    return SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer(
        app_client_id=config.client_id,
        tenant_id=config.tenant_id,
        scopes={
            f"api://{config.client_id}/user": "user",
        },
    )
```

Comment: The reason why it gets evaluated is because you import the reference directly and has defined it at the base level of the module; wrap it in a function and import the function: that function can then depend on the configuration as well; so: `dependencies=[Depends(get_azure_scheme)]`, `def get_azure_scheme(config: BaseConfig = Depends(get_config)): return SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer(...)`. Any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: It wouldn't work because `Depends` expects a callable, so `Depends(get_azure_scheme)` would be just calling `get_azure_scheme()`, returning some object and that's it. And the problem is, the `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer.__call__()` (or `get_azure_scheme()()` if you will) won't get executed that way

Comment: Yes, my point is that `get_azure_scheme` would be a _function_, so it would be a callable. This function would return the configured `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer`, since `get_azure_scheme` would have a `Depends` call on the function that returns the config (a common pattern shown in the FastAPI reference guide). So you'd have `get_azure_scheme(config: BaseConfig = Depends(get_config))` as shown in the comment above; I'm not sure what part of this that wouldn't work in your endpoint definition/dependency?

Comment: Instead of using `app.startup` as you do now, you'd wrap the function in a cache to avoid reading the config for every request. This is shown as an example in the reference guide: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/#the-main-app-file

Comment: I've updated the question. This is a complete example with all the imports, so you can even test it yourself, if you want. Anyway, it **does work** but it **doesn't**. And by "work" I mean - the server starts. However, the `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer` **doesn't get applied**. If I go to the `/docs`, there's no "Authorize" button, I can make requests to the `/test` endpoint freely, without any auth. And that's what I was talking about - `get_azure_scheme` is called, but its return value (`SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer()`) **is not**

Comment: I'm only starting to learn FastAPI, but from what I understand, if `Depends` expects a callable, then if I use `azure_scheme`, then it works because object of class `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer` is callable (it has `__call__()` method). And that's where the magic happens, I mean that's where the authorization gets applied to the endpoints. But in case of `get_azure_scheme`, only `get_azure_scheme()` gets called, not `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer().__call__()`

Comment: I guess the only way to do this would be to use `SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer` "manually" in `get_azure_scheme` - initialize it, figure out what arguments to pass to its `.__call__()` method, call it and return it